# Firestore security rules - checking for bool in a DB

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I don't know if i am able to ask this question properly, but here it goes...

I have a firebase collection, which has the bool field 'isAdmin'. So now when users are logging in, i want to set a rule to check whether this field is 'true', before allowing them access to another collection i got.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to define access based on a value in a document about the current user. For an example of that, have a look at the documentation on [attribute based access control](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics#attribute-based_and_role-based_access). Based on the example there:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // For attribute-based access control, Check a boolean `admin` attribute
    allow write: 
      if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.isAdmin
         == true;
    allow read: true;
  }
}
```

So here each user has a document in the `users` collection with the document ID the same as their UID, and the rule then gets that document and checks for the specific value you want.